# Wrapped coffeescript scope - use a variable's value for calling function

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

Edit: solved it myself.
I did the job by wrapping my code in a class, so @/this is referring to my object and not window

---

I'm writing a coffeescript script, without the use of Class. My javascript code is wrapped in an anonomous function:

```
(function() { ... }).call(this)
```

I have a list of checkboxes, like tomorrow, yesterday, next week, next month and so on. the user can select one or several of these. Instead of checking what the user has selected, I store these checkboxes classnames (tomorrow, nextWeek...). Instead of checking what class names I have, and then call the appropiate method, I have created methods corresponding to the class names.

If my tomorrow() was defined on the global scope I would call it like this:

```
this[expression]()
```

where expression hold the class name, for instance tomorrow.

for this to work I defined my function like this:

```
  this.tomorrow = function() {
       return console.log("I was triggered");
  };
```

tomorrow() is now defined on the global scope. Is there a way to not define the function in the global scope, without much effort?

Comment: What exactly is your question? If you have a globally defined function and `this` is the `windows` object, you can call your functions by `this[expression]()`.

Comment: @Amberlamps: Using coffeescript and wrapping is about not having you code cludder the global scope...

Comment: I know! Maybe you are phrasing your question a bit more accurate next time. If you are wrapping your code in an anonymous function and not touching the global scope in any way, how are you ever supposed to access those functions outside of the anonymous function? You could define a single object, that is globally accessible, and define all your function within that object.

Comment: @Amberlamps: The coffeescript compiler is adding the anonymous method, and adds .call(this) at the end. Look at the first line of code in my initial post. I don't need to access the methods from outside, so they don't need to be in the global scope.

Comment: I still do not know, what you are asking for???

Comment: That's great you solved it yourself! Feel free to answer your own question and mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the job by wrapping my code in a class, so @/this is referring to my object and not window.

```
@[expression]()
```

now works like intended